# Is there a difference between awaiting the last async call and just returning it?

Tags: c#, async-await

See question title.

In other words, given a method

```
async Task FrobnicateAsync() { ... }
```

is there any (maybe subtle) difference between

```
async Task FrobAndFrobnicateAsync()
{
    Frob();
    await FrobnicateAsync();
}
```

and

```
Task FrobAndFrobnicateAsync()
{
    Frob();
    return FrobnicateAsync();
}
```

Comment: Bill Wagner wrote a [blog post](http://thebillwagner.com/blog/Item/2017-05-03-ThecuriouscaseofasyncawaitandIDisposable) with *an* example of a potential difference, just yesterday.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43536642

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a blog post on [eliding async](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html).

Since you have a non-trivial `Frob` before the `await`, I recommend that you *keep* the `async` and `await`. The benefits of this approach are:

- If there is no `async` and `Frob` throws an exception, then the exception is thrown directly, which is surprising behavior for the consumers. Even if `Frob` doesn't throw an exception today, it can do so next year; thus the code with `await` is more maintainable.
- If there is no `async`, then `Frob` does not exist in the same logical call context as `FrobnicateAsync` (assuming it is actually `async`); instead, it would exist in the same logical call context as the caller of `FrobAndFrobnicateAsync`. This is not a concern in most code.

Also see [What Is the Purpose of return await?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098143/what-is-the-purpose-of-return-await-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

If you **literally** have the code shown, then you should prefer the `return FrobnicateAsync()` version - it avoids an extra layer of state machine abstraction and is simply more efficient.

If you have *additional* things - in particular any `finally` (including `using`) code that *surrounds* the `return`, then you must be sure to use the `await` version so that the `finally` code doesn't happen until *after* the `async` task has completed.

If in doubt, use the `async`/`await` version.

The good news is: it doesn't impact the signature (so is not a breaking change) to switch between them, so you can implement it the more efficient way now, and change to `async`/`await` if you find that you need to add a `using` block later.

As an additional thought: if you *usually* expect it to be completed synchronously, you can be more subtle:

```
Task FrobAndFrobnicateAsync()
{
    async Task Awaited(Task t) => await t;
    Frob();
    var task = FrobnicateAsync();
    // in .NET vFuture there will be a task.IsCompletedSuccessfully
    return task.State == TaskState.RanToCompletion ? task : Awaited(task);    
}
```

This avoids the state machine ***when not needed***.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd always agree with that - if `Frob` might throw an exception, there's quite a significant different in making it async. See Stephen Cleary's blog post on this: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html (In some cases I think it's fine, in others, not so much.)

Comment: @JonSkeet but you're not *absorbing* the difference; the *caller* should still be `await`-ing or whatever, so they'll get the exception *there* in the usual way

Comment: But that could be at a completely different point in their code. If this is a "bug in caller code" exception (e.g. validation) then I'm fine with that - if it's something like an `IOException`, then changing the point at which it's thrown feels more like a breaking change.

Comment: @JonSkeet ah, you mean exceptions inside `FrobAndFrobnicateAsync` before the call to `FrobnicateAsync`? Agreed: that is definitely a *difference*; it is a very complex conversation to discuss which version (if any) is *more correct*. Personally, I'm fine with it throwing in either way.

Comment: Yes, an exception in `Frob()`, exactly.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm perhaps also biased because most of the time I'm dealing with `async` is in *library* code that wraps multiple (many) smaller async operations, and I want to avoid allocating a `Task`/`TaskCompletionSource`, or dealing with the state-machine overheads **whenever remotely possible**; in *application* code (with more "chunky" APIs): then I'd probably prefer the `await` version.

Comment: On the other hand, in application code you're more likely to know about your callers and be able to change their expectations around exceptions if necessary :)

Comment: @JonSkeet it's almost as though async was complex and nuanced... almost...